# No route found for "GET /sf/customer-first-progam-level"

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-routing, symfony-3.2

As title shows I am having that issue if I try to reach the following URL:

```
http://app.local/sf/customer-first-progam-level
```

This is what I have:

- app/routing.yml

  ```
  quote:
      resource: "@QuoteBundle/Controller/"
      type:     annotation
      prefix:   /sf
  ```
- QuoteBundle/Controller/CustomerFirstProgramLevelController.php

  ```
  <?php

  namespace QuoteBundle\Controller;

  use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Method;
  use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
  use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
  use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

  /**
   * @Route("customer-first-program-level")
   */
   class CustomerFirstProgramLevelController extends Controller
   {
      use GridBuilder;

      /**
       * @Route("/", name="customer_first_program_level_index")
       * @Method({"GET", "POST"})
       * @param Request $request
       *
       * @return \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response
       * @throws \LogicException
       */
       public function indexAction(Request $request)
       {
           ...
       }
   }
  ```

This is what I have tried without success:

- Clear the cache both prod and dev
- Change the route name to something else

If I debug the `router` I got the following:

```
$ symfony_console debug:router
 ------------------------------------ ---------- -------- ------ -------------------------------------------- 
  Name                                 Method     Scheme   Host   Path                                        
 ------------------------------------ ---------- -------- ------ --------------------------------------------                          
  customer_index                       GET|POST   ANY      ANY    /sf/customer/                               
  customer_first_program_level_index   GET|POST   ANY      ANY    /sf/customer-first-program-level/           
  discount_index                       GET|POST   ANY      ANY    /sf/discount/                               
  ....          
 ------------------------------------ ---------- -------- ------ --------------------------------------------
```

I am using Symfony 3.2.7. Any ideas? I am out of them

Comment: Try http://app.local/sf/customer-first-progam-level/ with a slash on the end. If you want the url to be without the slash on the end change "/" to "" in the annotation

Comment: I agree with @FrankB. Your rest route is not complete

Comment: @FrankB that doesn't seems to be the issue, I have tried both adding the trailing slash and removing it from the route and still not working, this is weird, all my controllers has the same structure and none but this fails

Comment: The problem was that a `r` was missing in `progam`. I'm voting for closing this question since it was a typo.

Comment: Sometimes it is so simple that you dont see the problem :-) Thanks for the reply

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll answer myself and apologies for those who tried to answer but the issue was so ***dummy*** that no one found it (included myself). If you take a closer look to my test URL and the route definition you'll see there was a typo on the URL:

- URL: `/sf/customer-first-progam-level`
- @Route: `customer-first-program-level`

Problem `progam` (URL) vs `program` (route definition)

Answer (score -2):

Try `app.local/sf/customer-first-progam-level` with a slash on the end. If you want the url to be without the slash on the end change "/" to "" in the annotation